# Why I see pod running and also CrashLoopOff in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create PostgreSQL pods on k8s.
after the pod deploy when I use kubectl get pods I see out

```
NAME            READY        STATUS        RESTARTS         AGE   

pgadmin         1/1           Running       5                  9m
postgres        1/1           Running       5                8m
```

however when I run kubectl get pods -o wide then I see this output

```
pgadmin         0/1           CrashLoopBackOff         4    7m
postgres        0/1           CrashLoopBackOff         4     7
```

I am not sure why I see 2 different output.
when I run kubectl logs pgadmin-63545-634536   I see the following output

```
pgAdmin 4 - Application Initialisation
======================================

[2022-11-15 14:43:28 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-11-15 14:43:28 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:80 (1)
[2022-11-15 14:43:28 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
[2022-11-15 14:43:28 +0000] [90] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 90
[2022-11-15 14:44:24 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: term
[2022-11-15 14:44:25 +0000] [90] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 90)
[2022-11-15 14:44:26 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

Can you please explain me what is this behavior and why my pods shutdown ?
I am very new to K8s.
Thanks in advance.

I try to inspect the log file

Comment: You can also see this symptom if a pod's liveness probe never passes; it seems to start up, but never handles requests, and then gracefully terminates after several minutes.

Answer (score 0):

To answer why you are seeing two different outputs, you have to understand how a container runs in Kubernetes.

In docker, a container can run and then terminate, but then stay stopped unless you tell docker you want that container to automatically restart using the `--restart yes` switch

In a Kubernetes deployment (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), the `--restart yes` is implied -- namely, when a container (or "pod" in the Kubernetes world) exits, regardless of whether the exit was intentional or not, then Kubernetes will restart the container and will keep trying to restart it.

The exception to this is when you are running a `Job` (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) or `CronJob` (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/), which will run and restart until they complete successfully and then terminate, but that is beyond the scope of your question.

You can see from the "Restarts" count in your output that the number of restarts is increasing. Kubernetes will attempt to restart the exited containers as described above, but if it detects that it is restarting it repeatedly, it will start to add a "back off" period (i.e. it will add a delay before it tries to restart the container) -- during this delay period, the status of the pod will be "CrashLoopBackOff"

To answer why this is happening, you should describe the pod using `kubectl describe`. For example:

```
kubectl describe pod --namespace {name-of-namespace} pgadmin
```

This will give you details of the pod and look under the `Events` section -- it may have some details of what happened. Most likely the Liveness Probe (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) failed and therefore Kubernetes thinks the pods are dead, and restarts them accordingly.

Comment: Very helpful Really thanks. I use kubectl describe and found that there was a problem with storageclass.  I found and fix that issue but now my container are not starting up.           NAME                        READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE   IP       NODE    NOMINATED 
postgres-5bb9d69b96-4ln5m   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          42m   <none>   node2

Comment: Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  48m                    kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "ca9edd759802c00d3df3fce4345152f1a0b3152449cd11446c903499b7e9d03f": plugin type="calico" failed (add): error getting ClusterInformation: connection is unauthorized: Unauthorized

Comment: That looks like that a network plugin issue (hence the Calico reference). How are you running kubernetes?

Comment: I am setup Vmware esxi server one master with 3 nodes. all running ubuntu 20 and OS.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not had experience in that setup. Since your issue appears to now be a new issue, perhaps a separate question might be in order (tagged appropriately so that the right people pick it up)